# Terraform set GCP name tag Incorrect attribute value type error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

When I try to launch a new GCP instance with a name tag set as a variable I get this error:

```
terraform apply

Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main.tf line 32, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
  32:   tags = {
  33:     Name = var.instance_name
  34:   }

Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": set of string required.
```

This is how I have my resource defined in `main.tf`:

```
// A single Compute Engine instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = var.instance_name
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  zone         = "us-west1-a"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.instance_name}"
  }

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
```

This is how I have my variable setup in `variables.tf`:

```
variable "instance_name" {
  description = "Value of the Name tag for the EC2 instance"
  type        = string
  default     = "mysql-1"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `tags = [var.instance_name]` should work. `tags` cannot be a map, look at the docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance

Comment: Ok got it. That worked, thanks! Put that comment as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tags = [var.instance_name]` should work.  `tags` cannot be a map, see the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance).

Depending on what your goal is you could instead achieve the "tagging" via `labels`:

```
labels = {
  Name = var.instance_name
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks. How would I do multiple tags at once?

Comment: @TimDunphy `tags = [var.instance_name, "something", "else"]`